# expected value of fisher distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I know that the pdf of an F-distribution is $f_{k,m}(t) = \Gamma(t)=\frac{\Gamma((k+m)/2)}{\Gamma (k/2)\Gamma(m/2)}k^{k/2}m^{m/2}t^{k/2 - 1}(m+kt)^{-(k+m)/2}$

Also, $E(F)=\int xf_{k,m}dx$.

How do you evaluate this integral? Say you have to convert $x*f(k,m)$ to $C * f(k',m')$ where $f(k',m')$ is a pdf itself, which leaves $E(F)=C$ (which I know to be $\frac{m}{m-2}$).

How do I do this? Or can I do it another way? Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Definition**. Let $X \sim \chi^2_{k}$ and $Y \sim \chi^2_{m}$ be independent. Then
>       $$F = \dfrac{X/k}{Y/m}$$
>       follows the $F$-distribution with $(k, m)$ degrees of freedom.

It follows that

$$\mathbb{E}[F] = \dfrac{m}{k}\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{X}{Y}\right] = \dfrac{m}{k}\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{1}{Y}\right]=m\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{1}{Y}\right]$$
since $\mathbb{E}[X] = k$. Now use [this](http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/ChiSquare.html#mom5) and [this](http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Fisher.html#mom1).

Comment: Can you be clearer? The link shows $E(X^k)$. How can I apply? $E(Y^{-1})$?

Comment: @user3886450 $Y$ is $\chi^2$, and the hypothesis of the first link is that $X$ is $\chi^2$. So you can use the same result. I'm not sure how else to explain this.

Comment: @user3886450 I'm assuming you downvoted this. The second link *literally* solves it for you.